# Как в telegram-bot узнать сколько человек используют бот?

Tags: telegram-bot

Нужно, чтобы бот определил сколько человек его используют.

Есть какие нибудь методы?

Comment: Бот ваш? Записывайте в базу вызовы, собирайте статистику.

Comment: да, мой  можете какой не будь пример скинуть?

Comment: Нет, не могу. Если бот ваш, написан вами, то вам как программисту следует указать язык программирования, на котором он написан, какую базу вы используете, а главное - что именно вам непонятно в фразе "записывайте в базу вызовы"? Здесь помогают с конкретными вопросами.

Comment: Хорошо спасибо, нашел ответ ))

Comment: Извини, можно один вопрос я там написал не отвечают

Comment: Я например, создаю скидочный бот и хочу чтобы каждый пользователь мог только один раз в день получить скиду как это реализовать без разницы на каком языке желательно чтоб было на nodejs?

Comment: Ну если вам на любом языке - то реализуйте как угодно. В чём собственно вопрос? Берёте любой язык, читаете, как сохранять в базу, сохраняете. Может быть вы не программист и для вас такая задача слишком крупная? Тогда вам нужно начать с того, чтобы освоить азы. Здесь конечно отвечают на вопросы по программированию, но нужно понимать, что если у спрашивающего нехватка знаний - то надо начинать с основ. Это как... третьеклассник задаёт вопрос профессору про интегралы - но сам не особо даже понимает, что такое интеграл.

Comment: ясно, спасибо))